# Creating EasyMock mock throws NoSuchMethodError exception

Tags: java, easymock, cglib

I have created mock:

```
GuiExHandler mockGuiEx = EasyMock.createMock(MockedClass.class);
```

And Im getting following exception:

```
Testcase: testAction(someClass):
Caused an ERROR org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.<init>(I)V
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.<init>(I)V
```

I'm sure that `MockedClass` exists. What is the reason of this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EasyMock depends on [cglib](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/) which in turn depends on [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/).  From the exception, it appears cglib is calling an ASM constructor that does not exist.  So, the version of ASM being used is incompatible with the version of cglib being used.  Verify the versions of ASM and cglib you are using and confirm they are the versions supported by the version of EasyMock you are using.

Answer (score 0):

`cglib.nodep-2.2.2.jar` should be used instead of `cglib-2.2.2.jar`.

Comment: It would be helpful to include some information as to why this fixes the problem.

Comment: @helperDude: Please write what is the difference between the two.